# Skip to a new line in capybara

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara

I have a text box and i need to populate it and skip to a new line, manually I would just press "ENTER" but I'm struggling to figure out how I can do it in capybara. Any suggestions would help

Comment: Does it work if you just append `\n` to the string? Like, `"<text here>\n"`.

Comment: \n only works with some drivers. You're better off using the :return symbol in your send_keys call.